# Python basic threading issue

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

Trying to do a simple threading operation with queues. There's no run error, but my function isn't executing.

Heres my code:

```
data = ['1', '2', '3']

def do_stuff(arg1):
    print arg1

def start(num_threads):
    q = Queue.Queue()
    for item in data:
       q.put(item)

    for i in xrange(num_threads):
        t = threading.Thread(target=run, args=(do_stuff, q))
        t.start()

def run(func, queue):
    while queue:
        try:
            func(queue.get(False))
        except Queue.Empty:
            break

start(2)
```

Comment: did you import `threading` and `Queue`?

Comment: Sorry, works for me. I'm on ubuntu.

Comment: FYI, `Queue` doesn't implement `__len__` or `__bool__`/`__nonzero__`, so `while queue:` isn't actually testing anything meaningful (if it's called with a `Queue`, it's equivalent to `while True:`, which would be a reasonable and more obvious replacement since your `try`/`except`/`break` pattern will properly end the loop anyway).

Comment: works for me too on redhat